# How to divide background in 1 cell <td></td> based on value with [ngStyle] in Angular 7?

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to background a  in Angular 7 html based on value from SpringBoot API with [ngStyle].In one row I will divide it into 2 and if value is blue, the top row background will blue, and if value is orange the background of bottom row is orange.

I have already tried this way

```
<tbody *ngFor="let data of fData">
    <tr *ngFor="let task of tasks">
        <td nzLeft="0px">{{task.title}}</td>
        <td>{{data.actualStart}}</td>
        <td>{{data.actualFinish}}</td>
        <td>{{data.actualFinish - data.actualStart}}</td>
        <td>{{data.status}}</td>
        <td>{{data.keterangan}}</td>
        <td [ngStyle]="{'background-color': data.wplan32}">
            <div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': 
                             data.wplan32}"></div>
            <div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': 
                             data.wplan32}"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In css I have this,

```
.blue {
    background: rgb(0, 204, 255);
}

.orange {
    background: rgb(238, 255, 0);
}
```

I expected result in a row there are 2 background, but based on code above the row background that I get is none. If the I add

```
<div></div> value, example
<div>Blue</div>
```

I get background but only for the character not for entire row.
How can I solved this problem?
[Here is the result that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbcLh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ngStyle` you should use `ngClass`

```
 <td [ngClass]="{'blue': data.wplan32 === 'blue', 'orange': data.wplan32 === 'orange}"</td>
```